# Can I run commands from aws_s3 extensions as non-root on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I'm trying to copy data from S3 to PostgreSQL (Amazon AWS RDS). I've set up the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 cascade schema reporting;
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
\connect my_database;  -- reconnect to my_database
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
SET password_encryption = 'md5'; -- required by the Airflow connector I'm using
CREATE USER airflow_devel WITH PASSWORD 'my_password';
ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER airflow_devel;
ALTER USER airflow_devel IN DATABASE my_database SET search_path TO 'my_schema';
```

Then I run

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    '"table_name"',  /*table_name*/
    '',  /*empty column_list for all columns*/
     '(FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE, DELIMITER ''|'')',  /*options*/
    aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
        'my_bucket',
        'my/s3/key',
        'eu-central-1'
    )  /*s3_info*/
);
```

It runs fine using the master user.  However, when I run from just-created user `airflow_devel`, I get

```
permission denied for schema aws_s3
```

I haven't found an explanation on the internet why this function and extension should not be possible from non-root users.  But is this assumption wrong?  What does the message `permission denied for schema aws_s3` mean?  I mean, `aws_s3` is not a schema anyway.
I'm grateful for any advice or alternatives!

Comment: aws_s3 certainly is a schema.  It might *also* be the name of something else, too.  But that doesn't mean it isn't also a schema.

Comment: You created the extension in some database other than "my_database".

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In which DB the extension was created does not seem to matter so far.  Are extensions generally stored as schemas?  I can get one step further with `grant usage on schema aws_s3 to airflow_devel`, but then I get `permission denied for function table_import_from_s3`.

Answer (score 0):

With some research I found the solution was already given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535534/permission-denied-for-function-table-import-from-s3

We need to run

```
GRANT USAGE ON schema aws_s3 TO airflow_devel;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA aws_s3 TO airflow_devel;
```

That makes it work for me.